# Which runtime package is Comctl32.dll included with?

Tags: windows-xp

Which runtime package is Comctl32.dll included with? On a large number of our XP machines comctl32.dll isn't registered, is it part of some runtime that I can install?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC comctl32 is part of the [Platform SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/msdownload/platformsdk/sdkupdate/downlevel.htm).